# Ordenar array de objetos por fecha sin java.util.Arrays

Tags: java, array, clase, localdate

Estoy haciendo problemas a modo de práctica en Java —mañana tengo examen— y uno de los ejercicios era con una clase Libro con unos tantos atributos. Uno de ellos, el que más me importa ahora, es la fecha de compra, un LocalDate.
La cosa es que, como añadido al ejercicio principal, pide que ordenemos el array de 200 libros que generamos en el main por fecha; es decir, primero el más reciente y, por último, el más antiguo. Como dificultad, pone que no podemos usar los métodos de array, así que el .sort queda descartado :c

Le estoy dando vueltas y la verdad es que no consigo llegar a una solución que me convenza.

¿A alguien se le ocurre algo?

La clase libro, por cierto, sería algo así:

```
public class Libro {
    // atributos
    String titulo;
    String autor;
    String editorial;
    LocalDate fechaCompra;
    double precio;
    
    Libro(String titulo, String autor, String editorial, LocalDate fechaCompra, double precio){
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.editorial = editorial;
        this.fechaCompra = fechaCompra;
        this.precio = precio;
    }
    
    public LocalDate getFechaCompra(){
        return this.fechaCompra;
    }
    
    public double getPrecio(){
        return this.precio;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "El libro " + titulo + ", de " + autor + ", en la editorial " + editorial + ", cuesta " + precio + " y se adquirió el "+ fechaCompra;
    }
}
```

y la clase principal —todavía tengo que verificar algún posible error— es esta:

```
public class Hacedor {

   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Libro libros []= new Libro[200];
        Libro libroReciente [] = new Libro [1];
        boolean control = false;
        byte menu;
        int eleccionLibro;
        double precioMedio;
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        while(control != true){
            System.out.println("¿Qué quieres hacer?");
            System.out.println("1. Introducir libros");
            System.out.println("2. Visualizar datos almacenados");
            System.out.println("3. Mostrar libro más reciente");
            System.out.println("4. Mostras precio medio de todos los libros");
            System.out.println("0. Salir");
            menu = teclado.nextByte();
            
            switch(menu){
                case 1:
                    for (int i = 0; i < libros.length; i++) {
                        if(libros[i] != null){
                            libros[i] = crearLibro();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("¿Qué libro quieres ver? (1 - 200)");
                    eleccionLibro = teclado.nextInt();
                    libros[eleccionLibro].toString();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Este es el libro más reciente: ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < libros.length; i++) {
                        if((i+1) < libros.length){
                            if(libros[i].getFechaCompra().isBefore(libros[i+1].getFechaCompra())){
                                libroReciente[1] = libros[i];
                            }
                        }
                    } // fin del for
                    libroReciente[1].toString();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    precioMedio = precioMedio(libros);
                    System.out.println("El precio medio de los libros es: " + precioMedio + "euros.");
                    break;
                case 42:
                     
            } // fin del switch
        } // fin del while
    }
    
    static Libro crearLibro(){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        String titulo;
        String autor;
        String editorial;
        int año, mes, dia;
        LocalDate fechaCompra;
        double precio;
        Libro nuevoLibro;
        
        System.out.println("Inserta el título:");
        titulo = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Inserta el autor:");
        autor = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Inserta la editorial:");
        editorial = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Inserta la fecha de compra");
        System.out.println("¿Año?");
        año = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("¿Mes?");
        mes = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("¿Día?");
        dia = teclado.nextInt();
        fechaCompra = LocalDate.of(año, mes, dia);
        System.out.println("Inserta el precio:");
        precio = teclado.nextDouble();
        
        nuevoLibro = new Libro(titulo, autor, editorial, fechaCompra, precio);
        return nuevoLibro;
    }
    
    static double precioMedio(Libro libros[]){
        double mediaTotal = 0;
        
        for (Libro libro : libros) {
            mediaTotal += libro.getPrecio();
        }
        
        return mediaTotal/200;
    }
    
    
}
```

¡Un saludo!

Comment: Estudiate el metodo burbuja

Comment: ¡Gracias! Creo que puede ser una buena opción

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, déjame darte una mano.
Hay algunos errores en tu código, te describo a continuación.

1.No tiene sentido crear un arreglo de objetos con con una longitud de 1

```
Libro libroReciente [] = new Libro [1];
```

Si vas a crear un libro, haz lo siguiente

```
Libro libroReciente= new Libro (); //Para ello necesitas crear un constructor vacio en la clase Libro
```

2. Cuando validas un valor boolean no es necesario hacer una comparación

```
while(control != true)
```

esto puedes reemplazar por

```
while(!control)
```

3. Cuando llamas al metodo ToString, esto va devolver un cadena pero si no muestras por pantalla no va mostrar nada.

```
libros[eleccionLibro].toString();
```

Entonces lo que falta es mostrar en pantalla

```
System.out.println(libros[eleccionLibro-1].toString());
/*
Si visualizas estoy poniendo eleccionLibro-1, esto porque el arreglo comienza desde la posición 0
*/
```

4. Al comparar las fechas, si quieres que los más antiguos se ubiquen al principio tienes que usar `isAfter` en lugar de `isBefore`.
5. No es incorrecto pero debes acostumbrarte que el método `main` tenga la menos cantidad de código y crear otro método que realiza la labor de menu de opciones.

**Te comparto el código con las recomendaciones dadas.**

```
public class Hacedor {
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hacedor hacedor = new Hacedor();
        hacedor.menuPrincipal();
    }
    
    public void menuPrincipal(){
        Libro libros []= new Libro[200];
        Libro libroAuxiliar = new Libro();
        boolean control = false;
        byte menu;
        int eleccionLibro;
        double precioMedio;
        
        int contador=0;
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
                
        while(!control){
            System.out.println("¿Qué quieres hacer?");
            System.out.println("1. Introducir libros");
            System.out.println("2. Visualizar datos almacenados");
            System.out.println("3. Mostrar libro más reciente");
            System.out.println("4. Mostras precio medio de todos los libros");
            System.out.println("0. Salir");
            menu = teclado.nextByte();            
            
            switch(menu){
                case 1:
                    libros[contador]=crearLibro();                    
                    contador++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("¿Qué libro quieres ver? (1 - 200)");
                    eleccionLibro = teclado.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(libros[eleccionLibro-1].toString());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Este es el libro más reciente: ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < contador-1; i++) {
                        for(int j=1;j<contador;j++){
                            if(libros[i].getFechaCompra().isAfter(libros[j].getFechaCompra())){
                                libroAuxiliar=libros[j];
                                libros[i]=libros[j];
                                libros[j]=libroAuxiliar;
                            }                        
                        }
                    } // fin del for
                    System.out.println(libros[0].toString());
                    break;
                case 4: 
                    precioMedio=precioMedio(libros,contador);                   
                    System.out.println("El precio medio de los libros es: " + precioMedio + "euros.");
                    break;
                case 0:System.out.println("Salir");
                     
            } // fin del switch
        } // fin del while    
    }
    
    public Libro crearLibro(){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        String titulo;
        String autor;
        String editorial;
        int año, mes, dia;
        LocalDate fechaCompra;
        double precio;
        Libro nuevoLibro;
        
        System.out.println("Inserta el título:");
        titulo = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Inserta el autor:");
        autor = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Inserta la editorial:");
        editorial = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Inserta la fecha de compra");
        System.out.println("¿Año?");
        año = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("¿Mes?");
        mes = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("¿Día?");
        dia = teclado.nextInt();
        fechaCompra = LocalDate.of(año, mes, dia);
        System.out.println("Inserta el precio:");
        precio = teclado.nextDouble();
        
        nuevoLibro = new Libro(titulo, autor, editorial, fechaCompra, precio);
        
       
        return nuevoLibro;
    }
    
    public double precioMedio(Libro[] libros,int contador){
        double mediaTotal = 0;
        
        for(int i=0;i<contador;i++){
            mediaTotal+=libros[i].getPrecio();        
        }
        return mediaTotal/contador;
    }
}
```

**Posibles mejoras**

Al trabajar con arreglo estático en este caso declaras una longitud de 200, si no terminas de llenar todo el arreglo posiblemente vas a tener error de tipo `NullPointerException`, por ello prefiero trabajar con ArrayList que es de tipo dinámico.